# How to get the current angle of a sprite in Cocos2d v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am wanting to move a sprite in the the direction it is facing. I got everything I need except the sprites current angle. It is rotating back and forth like a pendulum forever, but when the button that moves it is tapped it stops rotating and moves in the direction it is currently facing, or at least thats what I want it to do, but I don't know how to get the value for the current angle. Could someone help me out? =)

Comment: What about sprite.rotation ?

Comment: Funny thing, I tried that earlier and it returned an error which baffled my mind, at least I think I did, but now it worked 0.o Well, thanks I guess, but just a quick question, the movement is in the wrong direction might that be because the      sprite.rotation  returns a degree value while the sin and cos functions take radiants? thanks though =)